# HTML, CSS application prototype - canvas, iframe or other

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, web

I im currently in the making of a mobile application (prototype), which need to created in html, css and js. I made a low-fidelity prototype with paper cards, but now i need to create it as a website.

I was thinking about setting in a picture of a smartphone (iphone/android) and then edit the content inside that screen to point out that it should be run on a smartphone.
So if you emagine a i picture of a smartphone, and then inside the screen i wanne create some kind of box where all my content should go, but i am not quite sure what the best way to do that is. Should i use a canvas, a iframe or something different?
If there are any other inputs you are more than welcome to fire them at me.
I created a video to see how a user, unknown to the project, would interact with my low fidelity prototype, and thats what i am building my html prototype from.
The video can be found here if it is to any interest.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVXhEwGYYfg

(don't mind the text, it is in danish and just describes what the user is dooing)

Hope you can give me a hand to get startet.

Regards,
Nissen, Michael